# Why does DATE in DB2 database have a time component in it?

Tags: date, db2, sqldatatypes, db2-luw

How can I make the column data type be `DATE` like YYYY-MM-DD;

when I create a table with the Data type DATE, it will become `TIMESTAMP(0)`

When I `ALTER SET DATA TYPE DATE`, it still is `TIMESTAMP(0)`
and `SELECT CHAR(CURRENT DATE, ISO) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;`
it will be error with SQLCODE=-171, CURRENT DATE is 2017-02-28 19:19:09.0
it's too long.

database info:DB2 linux x64 10.5

```
CREATE TABLE "XCRSUSR"."TIMP_TASK_SERIAL" (
        "SERIAL_NO" DECIMAL(16 , 0), 
        "TASK_NAME" VARCHAR(10), 
        "TASK_TYPE" DOUBLE, 
        "TASK_XML" CLOB(10) INLINE LENGTH 164, 
        "SEND_TIME" DATE, 
        "FINISH_TIME" DATE, 
        "TASK_STATUS" DOUBLE DEFAULT 0, 
        "RUN_TYPE" DOUBLE, 
        "FLAG" DOUBLE, 
        "TASK_ID" VARCHAR(10)
    )
    ORGANIZE BY ROW
    DATA CAPTURE NONE 
    IN "CREDIT_U_16" INDEX IN "CREDIT_INDEX_16"
    COMPRESS NO;

ALTER TABLE TIMP_TASK_SERIAL ALTER COLUMN SEND_TIME SET DATA TYPE DATE;
```

```
select CURRENT DATE from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1; 
 1
 ---------------------
 2017-02-28 19:19:09.0
```

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/zh/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0053667.html

Comment: If your database is in the Oracle compatibility mode, the `DATE` data type is in fact `TIMESTAMP` to mimic Oracle's, which has both data and time components. If you don't need Oracle compatibility, disable it; if you do, well, then it's expected behaviour.

Comment: yes,it really like that.so,how to disable Oracle compatibility,especial date_compat. only db2cmd?

Comment: i want to search the setting of date_compat. so i can test and verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the settings of the

> Oracle_Compatibility

vector under

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html

Bit Position 7 in table 1 is wjat you are looking for.

Comment: now,i want to have Oracle_Compatibility without Oracle_Compatibility .what's should set  DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR
why 03 mean both 1 (0x01) ROWNUM pseudocolumn and 2 (0x02) DUAL table

Comment: 70FFF-0x40=70FBF？
db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=70FBF

Comment: Note that 1) changing the compatibility vector for an existing database will not affect existing objects and 2) some features (e.g. `DUAL`) only take effect when the database is created.